# Bluetooth printer not printing (Android)

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am developing an application on android for my "Woosim S30/40" printer. Printer
is paired to my phone and there is no exception in the code. but when i write on blue-tooth socket, just the data light blinks slightly and nothing happens (no printing.) I ve tried many codes from stack over flow and apps form google store but same thing happens.
Printer sample paper displays the settings as follow

- Mode=Bluetooth
- Serial=57600 BPS
- 7 Data Bit
- ODD Parity
- 2 Stop Bit
- Density=Medium
- Mark=No USe
- Sensor=Low
- Command=type0
- PWDN= NO USe

Printing Event Code:(used from stack overflow)

```
mPrint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mPrint);
mPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View mView) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                    String BILL = "";
                    BILL = "\nInvoice No: ABCDEF28060000005" + "    " + "04-08-2011\n";
                    BILL = BILL + "-----------------------------------------";
                    BILL = BILL + "\n\n";
                    BILL = BILL + "Total Qty:" + "      " + "2.0\n";
                    BILL = BILL + "Total Value:" + "     " + "17625.0\n";
                    BILL = BILL + "-----------------------------------------\n";
                    os.write(BILL.getBytes());

                    // Setting height
                    int gs = 29;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(gs));
                    int h = 104;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(h));
                    int n = 162;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(n));

                    // Setting Width
                    int gs_width = 29;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(gs_width));
                    int w = 119;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(w));
                    int n_width = 2;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(n_width));

                    // Print BarCode
                    int gs1 = 29;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(gs1));
                    int k = 107;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(k));
                    int m = 73;
                    os.write(intToByteArray(m));

                    String barCodeVal = "ASDFC028060000005";// "HELLO12345678912345012";
                    System.out.println("Barcode Length : " + barCodeVal.length());
                    int n1 = barCodeVal.length();
                    os.write(intToByteArray(n1));

                    for (int i = 0; i < barCodeVal.length(); i++) {
                        os.write((barCodeVal.charAt(i) + "").getBytes());
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Main", "Exe ", e);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: You should contact the vendor of that Printer. Many bluetooth printers have their drivers, SDKs for android/IOS shipped along and they offer support for it.

Comment: http://www.woosim.com/english/bbs/message/download.list.do?messageCategoryId=13&boardId=4&messageId=69
they dont provice services for android..

Comment: They have android printers, so if your model is among that list you should be able to get SDK for it.. if not, then your printer is not supported or compatible with android connectivity..
http://www.woosim.com/english/bbs/message/message.list.do?boardId=4&messageCategoryId=59

Comment: I dont know what to do :( i ve found the official app for my printer on android app store.. but it works same... just blinking the light..
an Yes they listed my printer in android supported printers.

Comment: Then you should contact them, they must have on call support system.